# SVG icons enlarge in size after animation.

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I just made a very simple SVG animation **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/4u1s6xr3/2/)** . Now the probelem is , becuase i am animating the icons , like so:

```
$("#trophy-icon").css('animation-delay' , '3.3s')[0].classList.add('animated' ,'bounceInUp');
```

The icons on animation completion enlarge(if you remove the animation code in the jQuery , u'll see the icons remain the original size.) .

So how do i retain the size of the icons after animation ? one solution would be to resize the icon in a editor(illustrator etc.) , but i would have to be pixel perfect there , is there anyway i can edit the code so that the icon does't exceed a certain size ? (ohh and the solution must be responsive.)

Thank you.

Comment: It is because you are setting your scale through the `transform: matrix()` but when you set the `bounceInUp` animation, you reset the transform to `translate3d()`, thus removing the `matrix()`

Comment: @Kaiido whaoo ! thanks for pointing that out !